# Redirect POST request with additional form data in Spring

Tags: spring

I am developing a container app for my Angular frontend in Spring. I have a mock payment gateway, which I am submitting a Angular form using POST method.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/pay", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleMockPayment(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // APPEND MOCK PAYMENT STATUS CODE HERE (ResponseCode)
    // something like,
    // response.setParameter("ResponseCode", "1");

    request.setAttribute(View.RESPONSE_STATUS_ATTRIBUTE, HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT); // to allow redirecting POST requests

    return "redirect:/confirm";
}
```

In this mock controller, I need to append an additional data field to the original data received (which is the form submitted from Angular app). This data field is the mock payment success/failure code. This controller will then redirect to another controller, which is the real controller I am going to use to handle callback request from the payment server.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/confirm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String paymentVerification(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String orderId = request.getParameter("OrderID");
    String responseCode = request.getParameter("ResponseCode"); // this is null

    // do some stuff with orderId and responseCode
    // ...

    return "redirect:/booking";
}
```

The orderId is available as it was set from the initial form submission. But all the methods I tried (using Model, FlashParams, ... ), did not work (responseCode was null all the time).

How can I append this new parameter here?

Any alternative method to mock payment gateway is also appreciated. My goal is to either append a response code to the existing form data, or create a new form within the mock controller (`handleMockPayment`) with necessary mock attributes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `RedirectView` to achieve this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test/{id}")
public RedirectView handleMockPayment (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ...
    RedirectView rv = new RedirectView();
    rv.setContextRelative(true);
    rv.setUrl("/confirm/{responseCode}");
    return rv;
}
```

you can access same in `/confirm` using path variable.

Comment: Since the actual payment gateway sends response code as a form data and I am trying to build a mock payment gateway endpoint, I cannot send response code as a path variable. I somehow need to either append a response code to the existing form data, or create a new form within the controller with necessary mock attributes.